two namespaces with the same value in advancedfileoutputXML Talend
I have 2 namespaces with the same value


xmlns:(default) with static value http://www.energistics.org/energyml/data/prodmlv2
xmlns:prodml with static value http://www.energistics.org/energyml/data/prodmlv2
I created xmlns:(default) by emptying the prefix.

If I use those 2 namespaces, the appearance of the top part (header) is as I want, but the other tag parts cause the addition of "prodml:" in each xml tag.

But when I only use namespace 1, namely "xmlns:prodml" it produces another tag without prodml (as I expected) but the header is not as I expected (I want 2 namespaces to appear in the header)
If I empty the prefix section in the namespace, it will be the default, but I tried adding one letter variable, the tag is normal (but I want the header, namely xmlns = xxxxxx without prefix)
What is the solution so that the 2 namespaces can be displayed in the header and not make many additions of "prodml:" on each xml tag? Is there a solution to add a namespace without a prefix but not make it the default?
